# "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" with col-xs-12 center of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard loop for a photo gallery and I am using **[twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)** `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3` which gives me a 4 image across on desktop, scaling down to a single photo on mobile.

It all works good.

The one thing that is causing me vexation is that I want the single-across photo,  when viewing on mobile devices, to be center aligned on the page, but they are all left aligned.

So here is some basic pseudo of what I am doing:

```php
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach ($photos AS $photo) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <img src="pathtoimage">
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, the actual looping part, and the four across down to one across *all work perfectly*, I am just getting stuck on how to get the mobile view *(`col-xs-12`)* to be centered in the middle of the page, not left aligned.

Anybody know what the bootstrap magic to make this happen?

Comment: You can add `text-center` class to your div if it's OK to align the images on all break points. If it need to align them ONLY for mobile, then add one extra class and set `text-align: center;` only for mobile break point to this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the images with some CSS. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj_kooijmans/wL3pb54o/3/)

If you want the images to be centered only add certain breakpoints than you can use media queries to center them at certain breakpoints.

For example, to ccenter the images only on small screens:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .gallery-image img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-center` class to center image

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to use it? Don't answer like a comment. Explain completely with code.